# implode php array into formatted text

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode, array-map

I have this array:

```
array(122) { 
    ["1AB168820010"]=> array(3) { 
       ["MACHINE_NAME"]=> "L1XP2A"
       ["FEEDER_SLOT"]=> "114"
       ["REJECT_RATE"]=> float(0.0394) 
       ["DEFECT_QTY"]=> int(2) 
       ["SOLDER BALL"]=> int(2) 
    }  
    ["1AB037870031"]=> array(5) { 
       ["MACHINE_NAME"]=> "L2CP7A"
       ["FEEDER_SLOT"]=> "155"
       ["REJECT_RATE"]=> float(2.3022) 
       ["DEFECT_QTY"]=> int(39) 
       ["COMPONENT TOMBSTONED"]=> int(31) 
       ["SOLDER BALL"]=> int(2) 
       ["COMPONENT BILLBOARD"]=> int(6)
    } 
    ["1AB144890021"]=> array(7) { 
       ["MACHINE_NAME"]=> "L21P3A"
       ["FEEDER_SLOT"]=> "214"
       ["REJECT_RATE"]=> float(0.0225) 
       ["DEFECT_QTY"]=> int(8) 
       ["SOLDER INSUFFICIENT "]=> int(2) 
       ["SOLDER BAD"]=> int(2) 
       ["SOLDER BALL"]=> int(2) 
       ["COMPONENT MISSING"]=> int(1) 
       ["COMPONENT BILLBOARD"]=> int(1) 
    } 
    ["1AB144890033"]=> array(7) {
       ["MACHINE_NAME"]=> "L1CP7A"
       ["FEEDER_SLOT"]=> "234" 
       ["REJECT_RATE"]=> float(0.0142) 
       ["DEFECT_QTY"]=> int(7) 
       ["SOLDER INSUFFICIENT "]=> int(1) 
       ["SOLDER BAD"]=> int(1) 
       ["COMPONENT MISSING"]=> int(3) 
       ["COMPONENT SKEW"]=> int(1) 
       ["COMPONENT TOMBSTONED"]=> int(1) 
    }
    #...more
}
```

I need to loop through the array and create a string from the array output that looks like this but don't know the best way...please help

```
 1AB168820010 ( 0.0394% ) #<-this is the 'REJECT_RATE'
  -Machine: L1XP2A
  -Feeder: 114
     SOLDER BALL ( 100% ) #<-'SOLDER BALL' value (2) divided by 'DEFECT_QTY' (2) * 100
 ------------------------
 1AB037870031 ( 2.3022% ) 
  -Machine: L2CP7A
  -Feeder: 155
     COMPONENT TOMBSTONED ( 79.48% ) #<- ( 31 / 39 ) * 100
     COMPONENT BILLBOARD ( 15.38% )  #<- ( 6 / 39 ) * 100
     SOLDER BALL ( 5.12% ) #<- ( 2 / 39 ) * 100
 ------------------------
 1AB144890021 ( 0.0225% )
  -Machine: L2IP3A
  -Feeder: 214
     SOLDER INSUFFICIENT ( 25% )
     SOLDER BAD ( 25% )
     SOLDER BALL ( 25% )
     COMPONENT MISSING ( 12.5% )
     COMPONENT BILLBOARD ( 12.5% )
 ------------------------
 1AB144890033 ( 0.0142% )
  -Machine: L1CP7A
  -Feeder: 234
     SOLDER INSUFFICIENT ( 14.3% )
     SOLDER BAD ( 14.3% )
     COMPONENT MISSING ( 42.8% )
     COMPONENT SKEWED ( 14.3% )
     COMPONENT TOMBSTONED ( 14.3% )
```

My main issue I'm not sure how to handle is that I don't know the number of defects (i.e. COMPONENT MISSING, COMPONENT SKEWED, SOLDER BAD) per partnumber, how many defects (and what defects it has) will vary, therefore I can't just hard-code 'COMPONENT MISSING: [some calc]' into my foreach loop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Optionally, you can sort the array by its keys: `ksort($array);`.)

Next, you iterate over each element and build the string:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
  $output .= $key . ' ( ' . number_format($data['REJECT_RATE'], 3) . '% )' . "\n";
  $output .= ' -Machine: ' . $data['MACHINE_NAME'] . "\n";
  $output .= ' -Feeder: ' . $data['FEEDER_SLOT'] . "\n";
  $output .= '  SOLDER BALL ( ' . number_format(2 / $data['DEFECT_QTY'] * 100, 0) . '% )'. "\n";

  // Add more calculation here…

  $output .= "------------------------\n";
}
```

And finally, you output the string: `echo $output;`.

Comment: Why sort the array? The OP never asked for that.

Comment: Guess my brain did some sort of auto-sorting… I checked again and indeed, the desired output was not sorted. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches: simple and 'right' :)

Simple approach:

```
foreach ($array as $machine_key=>$machine){
    $solder_ball = $machine['SOLDER_BALL']/ $machine['DEFECT_QTY']*100;
    echo "$machine_key ({$machine['REJECT_RATE']})";
    echo " -Machine {$machine['MACHINE_NAME']};
    echo " -Feeder {$machine['FEEDER_SLOT']}";
    echo "  SOLDER INSUFFICIENT ( $solder_ball%)";
    //...and so on...//
}
```

'Right' approach

Have class `Machine`:

```
class Machine{
    $protected $name, $feeder, $solder_insufficient; //..all youneed to output here..//
    function__constructor(Array $params){
        $this->name = $params['MACHINE_NAME'];
        $this->solder_insufficient = $machine['SOLDER_BALL']/ $machine['DEFECT_QTY']*100;
        //..all other params here...//
    }

    function output(){
        echo "{$this->key} ({$this->reject_rate)";
        echo " -Machine {$this->key}";
        echo " -Feeder {$this->feeder}";
        echo "  SOLDER INSUFFICIENT ( {$this->solder_insufficient}%)";
        //....and so on ..//
    }
}
```

The benefit ofusing 'right' approach is that youcan reuse your class multiple times, and adjust output in all placesthat require it by modifying code at single place only.

Answer (score 1):

this could work

```
foreach($arr as $id => $item) {
  printf('%s ( %s )
  -Machine: %s
  -Feeder: %s
',
  $id,
  $item['REJECT_RATE'],
  $item['MACHINE_NAME'],
  $item['FEEDER_NAME']);
  foreach($item as $key => $val) {
    if(!in_array($key, array('REJECT_RATE', 'MACHINE_NAME', 'FEEDER_NAME', 'REJECT_QTY'))) {
      printf("    %s ( %s )\n", $key, 100*$val/$item['REJECT_QTY']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a `foreach` loop that loops through each object in the array and outputs them accordingly.  The example below should be modified to fit your styling, but it should give you the basis to get started:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Item</th><th>Value</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($myArray as $k => $v){
    echo "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td></tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yea I figured I could do something like that, I wasn't sure if there was an array_map type of function combined with some further formatting that would allow me to avoid using another loop in my script

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` to iterate through the values and format the output string as desired.

```
foreach( $your_array as $id => $details ) {
    foreach( $details as $key => $value ) {
        //format your desired output
    }
}
```